# XeF4 - why are there only 2 dihedral mirror planes?

Tags: symmetry

I started studying molecular symmetry and I became somehow confused about *dihedral mirror planes*. I found a definition, which says,  that it is a *vertical mirror plane, which bisects two $C_2$ axes*.

But when I look at $\ce{XeF4}$ molecule, I see, that it has 4 $C_2$ axes and 4 vertical mirror planes. All of those planes are bisecting 2 $C_2$ axes and both all of them also go through some atom.

Still, there are only 2 dihedral mirror planes $\sigma_\mathrm{d}$ and the remaining two planes are just common vertical ones $\sigma_\mathrm{v}$.

So, could you please tell me what's the real difference between vertical and dihedral mirror planes?

OK, in a link given in [comments by Tyberius](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87070/xef4-why-are-there-only-2-dihedral-mirror-planes#comment157285_87070) is said, that dihedral planes are such planes, which bisects as many bonds as possible, while "normal" vertical planes bisects as many atoms as possible. Then I don't get, why ethene (see the picture below) doesn't have one dihedral plane, as one of them clearly bisects its central bond and we can't symmetrically bisect more bonds in this molecule.

---

#### $\ce{XeF4}$

[image]

---

#### Ethene

[image]

Comment: http://www.chembio.uoguelph.ca/educmat/chm2060_preuss/L3-2013.pdf

Comment: @Tyberius Ok, now I see "bisects as many bonds as possible"... Could you, please, tell me then, why there is no $\rho_d$ in [Ethene](http://www.chemtube3d.com/Sym-D2hethene.htm)? I think, that one of the vertical planes should be dihedral, as it bisects the central double bond and there is no larger number of bonds to be bisected symmetrically.

Comment: It's in the definition you quoted: 'bisects two C2 axes'.

Comment: @orthocresol I thought about that, but while I didn't find it in the provided slideshow, I thought it's not correct...

Comment: It probably depends on the text, I'm not sure if there's one single authoritative source. Cotton's *Chemical Applications of Group Theory* (3rd ed., p 53) says that the use of $\sigma_v'$ vs. $\sigma_d$ is "somewhat arbitrary", but other textbooks say that $\sigma_d$ planes need to bisect C2 axes. Incidentally, if you look up the character table for $D_\mathrm{2h}$ you'll probably find that all three mirror planes are conventionally labelled with just $\sigma$.

Comment: @orthocresol Ok, thank you very much. Could you, please, write a short answer, so I could accept/upvote it?

Comment: @Tyberius Could you, please, write a short answer, so it could be accepted/upvoted?

Comment: I took the liberty to rearrange the structures on the pictures horizontally so that users with smaller or wider screens could compare them both without scrolling back and forth; plus I changed the notations for mirror planes from $\rho$ to more common $\sigma$ (see [How are point group character tables typeset correctly?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32894/how-are-point-group-character-tables-typeset-correctly)). If you are unhappy with this, please feel free to rollback to the original version:)

Comment: Strongly related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23954/why-does-symmetry-have-to-be-maintained-in-molecular-orbitals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it seems that the use of $\sigma_\mathrm{v}$ vs $\sigma_\mathrm{d}$ is basically a matter of convention when both terms can be applied. Really, even $\sigma_\mathrm{h}$ vs $\sigma_\mathrm{v}$ is somewhat arbitrary if there isn't a single clear principal axis.

By a certain [convention](http://www-e.openu.ac.il/symmetry/symmetry-tutorial.html) $\sigma_\mathrm{d}$ are vertical mirror planes that bisect $2C_2$ axes. When there are multiple mirror planes that fit this criteria, those that cut through the most atoms are referred to as $\sigma_\mathrm{v}$, while the others are called $\sigma_\mathrm{d}$.

This again is somewhat arbitrary and can be ambiguous. In particular, for $D_\mathrm{2h}$ molecules like ethene any of the mirror planes could fit the description for $\sigma_\mathrm{h}$ depending on which $C_2$ you say is the principal. For this point group, you can unambiguously label the axes and planes using the [Cartesian axes](http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=602&option=4)

Answer (score 7):

This is a situation of coordinate systems. In the $D_\mathrm{4h}$ point group, as you've noticed, there are 4 $C_{2}$ rotation axes in the plane. The easiest way to set the coordinate system is to have one pair be coincident with the $x$ and $y$ axes and the other pair coincident with the functions $x=y$ and $x=-y$.

Herein lies the issue: which pair is which? I think most people would agree that a reasonable choice is that the primary set should be coincident with the Cartesian axes. Indeed, an example [character table](http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=604&option=4) for this group makes this choice as well (these are the $C_{2}'$ elements). This then defines which pair of mirror planes are $\sigma_\mathrm{d}$ and which pair are $\sigma_\mathrm{v}$.

This covers $\ce{XeF4}$ only, not ethene, because ethene belongs to the $D_\mathrm{2h}$ point group.

Here's the [character table](http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=602&option=4) for that group. There's no dihedral mirror plane because the mirror planes perpendicular to the plane of molecule are coincident with the rotation axes.